# how to create a new environment like chapter in a book that reads as "Unit"?

Tags: environments

For a book (lecture notes) I am writing for an M. Tech course, I like the name the 5 Chapters as 5 Units (Unit 1, Unit 2, Unit 3, Unit 4, Unit 5). How to do this? Thanks for great help!

Comment: `\def\chaptername{Unit}`

Comment: Thanks - I tested it - It works very well for me. Great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also implement
`\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Unit}`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! Great help!